# Cómo hago para que se resten las 2 variables? java netbeans gracCa

Tags: java

Me sale en rojo probé ponerles paréntesis y nada si se suman pero no se restan. Estoy aprendiendo java desde 0

```
System.out.println("Pedro mide "+alturaP-alturaJ+" mts mas que juan");
```

Comment: Puedes poner el codigo completo?

Comment: Lo que podrías hacer es declarar una variable donde los restes y luego, en vez de hacer la resta en el println, directamente pasar la variable con ya el resultado.

Answer (score 0):

```
"Pedro mide "+alturaP-alturaJ+" mts mas que juan"
```

Para los ejemplos, supondremos `alturaP = 180` y `alturaJ = 171`.

El compilador analiza la expresión en función de los paréntesis, la prioridad de los operandos y, si todo es igual, de izquierda a derecha.

Pero el operador `+` es distinto según sean los operandos:

- Si los dos operandos son numéricos, el resultado es un número (la suma): 3 + 9 --> 12
- Si uno de los operandos es un `String`, el resultado es un `String` (la concatenación del `String` con la representación del número como `String`): "hola " + 9 --> "hola 9"

El operador `-` solo está definido cuando los dos operandos son numéricos.

Así que primero hace

```
"Pedro mide " + alturaP --> un String, "Pedro mide 180"
```

Y luego intenta hacer

```
"Pedro mide 180" - alturaJ
```

Pero el operando `-` no tiene sentido con un `String`, así que lanza el error de compilación.

Solución: Agrupa la resta entre paréntesis para que, a la hora de evaluar la expresión, te reemplace el contenido por el resultado de la operación

```
"Pedro mide " + (alturaP - alturaJ) + " mts mas que juan"
```

O sea

```
"Pedro mide " + (alturaP - alturaJ) 
     -- Hay que calcular el paréntesis, se hace la resta --> "Pedro mide " + 9
     -- concatenación --> "Pedro mide 9"
```

Answer (score 0):

Tiene que indicarle que se hará una operación

```
System.out.println("Pedro mide " + (alturaP-alturaJ) + " mts mas que juan");
```